# PHP, HTML5 and Javascript: only first entry of (dynamic) array gets posted

Tags: javascript, php, html, apache

Code below is working as expected on one server but fails on another. The expected behaviour is after adding some filter values and apply filter the filter values should stay there.

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
  // Initialisation
  $numbersPerPage = array( "10", "25", "50", "100" );
  $filterOptions  = array( "",
                           "one",
                           "two",
                           "three",
                         );
?>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style>thead {color:black;font-weight: bold}
           tbody {color:black;}
           tfoot {color:red;}
           table,th,td
           table {table-layout:fixed;word-wrap:break-word;}
    </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Track & Trace</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Track and trace main page">
    <meta name="author" content="Marc Fellman">
    <meta name="google" value="notranslate">
    <script language="javascript">
      <!--
      //Browser Support Code
      function filterOption(action,loc){
        num = parseInt(loc.split("-")[1]) + 1;
        tableNode = document.getElementById("Filters");
        if ( action.trim() == "add" ) {
          newRow  = tableNode.insertRow(tableNode.rows.length - 1);
          newRow.id = "Filter-" + newRow.rowIndex;
          newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
          newRemoveButton = document.createElement("span");
          newRemoveButton.innerHTML = '<button type="button" onclick="filterOption(\'remove\',\'Filter-' +
            newRow.rowIndex.toString() + 
            '\')">removeFilterOption</button>';
          newSelectionInput = document.createElement("input");
          newSelectionInput.type = "text";
          newSelectionInput.name = "filterValue[]";
          newSelectionInput.id   = "filterValue[]";
          newSelectionInput.size = 60;
          newSelectionKey = document.createElement("span");
          insideHTML = "<select name='filterKey[]' id='filterKey[]' class='input'>";
<?php
          for ($index=0; $index < count($filterOptions); $index++) {
            print " insideHTML = insideHTML + '<option>" . $filterOptions[$index] . "</option>';";
          }
?>
          insideHTML = insideHTML + "</select>";
          newSelectionKey.innerHTML = insideHTML;
          newCell.appendChild(newSelectionKey);
          newCell.appendChild(newSelectionInput);
          newCell.appendChild(newRemoveButton);
        }
        if (action.trim() == "remove") {
          rmNode = document.getElementById(loc);
          rmNode.parentNode.removeChild(rmNode);
        }
      }
      //-->
    </script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <form action='indextest.php' method='post'>
      <table>
        <tr><td width="20px"></td><td>
<?php
  // var_dump($_POST);

  if (isset($_POST['filterKey'])) {
    $filterKey = $_POST['filterKey'];
  } else {
    $filterKey = array();
  }
  if (isset($_POST['filterValue'])) {
    $filterValue = $_POST['filterValue'];
  } else {
    $filterValue = array();
  }
  if (isset($_POST['transID'])) {
    $transID = $_POST['transID'];
  } else {
    $transID = "";
  }
  if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
  } else {
    $action = "first";
  }
  if (isset($_POST['perPage'])) {
    $perPage = (int) $_POST['perPage'];
  } else {
    $perPage = 10;
  }

  $result = null;
?>
  <table width='100%' id="Filters">
    <tr><td>FILTERS</td></tr>
<?php
    if (isset( $filterKey )) {
      for ($keyIndex=0; $keyIndex < count($filterKey); $keyIndex++) {
        $newRow = $keyIndex + 1;
        print "<tr id='Filter-" . $newRow . "'>";
        print "  <td>";
        print "    <span>";
        print "      <select name='filterKey[]' id='filterKey[]' class='input'>";
        for ($index=0; $index < count($filterOptions); $index++) {
          if ( $filterOptions[$index] == $filterKey[$keyIndex]) { 
            print " insideHTML = insideHTML + '<option selected>" .
              $filterOptions[$index] . "</option>';";
          } else {
            print " insideHTML = insideHTML + '<option>" . $filterOptions[$index] . "</option>';";
          }
        }
        print "      </select>";
        print "    </span>";
        print "    <input type='text' name='filterValue[]' id='filterValue[]' size='60' value='" .
          $filterValue[$keyIndex] . "'/>";
        print "    <span>";
        print "      <button type='button' onclick='filterOption(\"remove\",\"Filter-" .
          $newRow . "\")'>removeFilterOption</button>";
        print "    </span>";
        print "  </td>";
        print "</tr>";
      }
    }
?>
    <tr id="Filter-0">
      <td>
        <button type='button' onclick="filterOption('add','Filter-0')">addFilterOption</button>
        <button type='submit'>applyFilter</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table width="100%" border="0">
    <thead>
      <tr bgcolor="#2EFEF7">
        <th width="35px">col0</th>
        <th width="180px">col1</th>
        <th width="80px">col2</th>
        <th>col3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
<?php

?>
  </table> 

<?php
    print "  <input type='hidden' id='transID' name='transID' value='" . $transID . "'/>";
    print "  <table width='100%'>";
    print "    <tr bgcolor='#2EFEF7'>";
    print "      <td align='left'>";
    print "        <input id='action' name='action' type='submit' value='first'/>";
    print "        <input id='action' name='action' type='submit' value='backward'/>";
    print "      </td>";
    print "      <td align='center'>";
    print "        Lines per page :";
    print "        <select class='input' name='perPage' id='perPage'>";
    for ($index=0; $index < count($numbersPerPage); $index++) {
      print "        <option value='" . $numbersPerPage[$index] . "'";
      if ( (int) $numbersPerPage[$index] == $perPage ) {
        print " selected";
      }
      print "/>" . $numbersPerPage[$index] . "</option>";
    }
    print "        </select>";
    print "        <input id='submit' name='submit' type='submit' value='adjust'/>";
    print "      </td>";
    print "      <td align='right'>";
    print "        <input id='action' name='action' type='submit' value='forward'/>";
    print "        <input id='action' name='action' type='submit' value='last'/>";
    print "      </td>";
    print "    </tr>";
    print "  </table>";
?>
        </td><td width="20px"></td></tr>
      <table>
      </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I added some additional code to work on the debugging:

```php
<?php
print "CONTENT_TYPE: " . $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] . "<BR />";
$inputdata = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = array();
parse_str($inputdata,$data);
print "DATA: <pre>";
var_dump($inputdata);
var_dump($data);
print "</pre>";
?>
```

That gave me almost identical outputs:

```
    CONTENT_TYPE: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    DATA:
    string 'filterKey%5B%5D=&filterValue%5B%5D=AAAA&filterKey%5B%5D=&filterValue%5B%5D=BBBB&transID=d8018bc2-9252-dea6-e511-dd859c5c183b&perPage=10' (length=135)
    array (size=4)
      'filterKey' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string '' (length=0)
          1 => string '' (length=0)
      'filterValue' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'AAAA' (length=4)
          1 => string 'BBBB' (length=4)
      'transID' => string 'd8018bc2-9252-dea6-e511-dd859c5c183b' (length=36)
      'perPage' => string '10' (length=2)
```

and

```
    CONTENT_TYPE: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    DATA:
    string(135) "filterKey%5B%5D=&filterValue%5B%5D=AAAA&filterKey%5B%5D=&filterValue%5B%5D=BBBB&transID=d8018bc2-9252-dea6-e511-dd859c5c183b&perPage=10"
    array(4) {
      ["filterKey"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
      ["filterValue"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(4) "AAAA"
      }
      ["transID"]=>
      string(36) "d8018bc2-9252-dea6-e511-dd859c5c183b"
      ["perPage"]=>
      string(2) "10"
    }
```

The big difference seems to be that one version is processing the Array slighly different from the other (5.3 shows 1 entry).

I guess it is a php or Apache setting or extension that I'm missing. I installed a default wampserver on the server that is working as expected and a minimal install on a OpenSuse server that has issues in remembering every option except the first.

Comment: narrow down your code to the problem area, or post multiple questions

Comment: I tried to narrow it down. I'm using the AJAX to add input fields to the web page but after adding several of them only the first one gets passed along (and at the moment it even deems to be failing on that on the OpenSUSE server). I think it is somehow session related but still haven't found a setting that solves this.

Comment: I just noticed that the server that only returns the first value is on PHP 5.3 and the server that is generating expected results is on PHP 5.5. I also tried to do a parse_str on the php://input but that still only keeps the first item of the array.

Comment: Definitely a PHP or Apache issue. I'm not sure yet which module is acting up or missing or whatever but I was able to replicate the configuration of a working server to the server that had issues and now it is working. Probably something todo with a module in PHP is my guess. Had to install (5.2 versions) a few more of the modules to replicate the working instance.